# How to "Ctrl-F" in iPhone's Safari browser?

Tags: iphone, mobile-safari, search

Most browsers have a "search" or "find" function (accessible through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>) which allows us to search the webpage for text.

Does iPhone's Safari browser have this functionality?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have an iPhone anymore, but my memory tells me this:

## iPhone

Search using the standard search bar.

- The **web search** suggestions are at the top.
- The **website search** results of the currently viewed website are at the bottom.

## iPad

Search using the standard search bar.

- The **web search** suggestions are at the top.
- To search the website use the entry box which pops up right above the keyboard.

All of this may change with iOS 6 and Mountain Lion. The WWDC2012 announced that Safari for OSX will integrate a Chrome like omnisearch bar . Most likely we'll see something similar for iOS as well - at least i hope so :).

Comment: What do you mean by the "standard search bar"? I can only see the "address bar" and the "google search bar"..

Comment: @Pacerier Sorry that I wasn't clear enough. I mean what you refer to as the "google searchbar" - which actually is not the real name as you can change it to Bing or Yahoo for example.

Comment: Cool its working =) Wow, talk about bad usability..